# how to switch or highlight arguments in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For the sake to explain my question I write the following line of python code,

```
html_res.find('#footer', first=True)
```

I want to ease editing arguments in VS code such that the usual way consists of combining `shift` with `ctrl` keys and arrow keys to select an argument, however, in a large code file this is time consuming.
In the above line of code, suppose that the cursor is in the front, the shortcut I'm asking allows selecting `'#footer'` at once, then using that shortcut once again switches to and highlights `first=True`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by)

add this to your `settings.json`

```json
  "selectby.regexes": {
    "nextParameter": {
      "forward": "(?<=\\(|, |,)(?=[^ ])",
      "forwardNext": ", ?|\\)",
      "forwardNextInclude": false
    }
  }
```

If you also want to go back you need to use the extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) to combine multiple calls

add this to your `settings.json`

```json
"multiCommand.commands": {
  "multiCommand.prevParameter": {
    "sequence": [
      { "command": "moveby.regex", "args": { "regex": "(\\(|, |,)(?=[^ ])", "properties": ["prev", "start"], "repeat": 2}},
      { "command": "selectby.regex", "args": ["nextParameter"] }
    ]
  }
}
```

See both extension pages on how to bind a key to these commands.

Comment: what if I want to use it backward?

Comment: @EnthusiastiC see the edit

Comment: you might intend to add and enclose the whole code with `[]` and edit the second line such that it would look like
`"command": "multiCommand.prevParameter",` without the suffixed braces should make the code works as expected

Comment: @EnthusiastiC `multiCommand.commands` has the option of an array or an object, the object makes it possible to merge global and workspace settings